# compare string stored in string resource in android?

Tags: android

I have a button on which (like) is written from string resource, on click I want to toggle like to unlike & vice verse.

How to compare button contain like or unlike from string resource?

My string.xml contains

```
<string name="like">Like</string>
<string name="unlike>unlike</string>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this..

```
bt.setText(getString(R.string.txt1));
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myStr = bt.getText().toString();
        if((myStr.equals(getString(R.string.txt1)))) {
            bt.setText(getString(R.string.txt2));
        } else if ((myStr.equals(getString(R.string.txt2)))) {
            bt.setText(getString(R.string.txt1));
        }
    }
});
```

In string.xml

```
<string name="txt1">11111111111</string>
<string name="txt2">2222222222222222</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use getString method

```
 if(btn1.getText().toString().compareTo(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)) == 0)
    {
      // do some code here
    }
```

Comment: say button id is btn1 & in string resource string name are like & unlike then

Answer (score 2):

use below code

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

if(button.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.like)))
{
    button.setText(getString(R.string.unlike));
}
else
{
    button.setText(getString(R.string.like));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try as:

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.texttest);
Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btntest);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if(button.getText().toString().equals(text))
    {
      // do some code here
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the label (Text on Button) in this manner.

```
Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Log.d("Text",""+button.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this::

```
String value=buttonname.getText().toString   

//this Will Give the Text On the Button
```

Now compare the value like this Way and change the Name Of the Button::

```
if(value.equals("Like"))  
 {
   buttonname.setText("UnLike"); 
 }
else
{
  buttonname.setText("Like");
}
```